# DotNetNuke Upgrade Error

Tags: compilation, dotnetnuke

I have an issue updating to the newest version. Could there be an issue with my web.config file? I can't access the admin functionality.

Comment: Can you give some examples of errors?

Comment: This sounds more like a configuration problem then anything.

Comment: Which config? Why would this work as un-compiled code, and not after its built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your web.config is confused between choosing 3.5 and 2.0 libraries.

```
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Management, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
  </assemblies>
```

This is roughly what it should be in DNN 4. If you have some 3.5 libraries sprinkled in it. try removing it.

I ran into this issue before, that's how i know.

Comment: Good work sir, I'm impressed you were able to come up with a specific solution to such a vague question :)